# retrieve data from firebase with authentication user do not show on ListView

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I want to retrieve data from firebase with authentication user. I use ListView to display the data. But it do not show up after running.
[image: My firebase structure]

```
public class InfoDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listViewINFO;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    List<UserInformation> infoList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_display);

        listViewINFO = findViewById(R.id.listViewINFO);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class));
        }
        //FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Information");
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String UserID = user.getUid();
        databaseReference.child("User Information").child(UserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot INFOSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserInformation  userInfo = INFOSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                    infoList.add(userInfo);
                }
                UserInfoAdapter userInfoAdapter = new UserInfoAdapter(InfoDisplayActivity.this, infoList);
                listViewINFO.setAdapter(userInfoAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEmq1B1gveM&index=2&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hj6SDHf_YybDeVhUT9MXaj1) tutorial on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using the `User Information` reference twice. Once when declaring the `databaseReference` object:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Information");
//                                                                      ^
```

And second when you attach the listener:

```
databaseReference.child("User Information").child(UserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
//                              ^
```

To solve this, simply remove `.child("User Information")` from the above line of code:

```
databaseReference.child(UserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It work. But what if I want to retrieve data from all user.

Comment: In that case you need to iterate the database twice. You should make your own attempt given the information in the comment and ask another question if something else comes up.